# Custom widget design time support?

Tags: c#, mono, monodevelop, gtk#

The GUI designer for MonoDevelop (Stetic) provides design-time support for widgets, such as the Notebook widget, which has options for **Insert Page Before** and **Insert Page After**. It also allows me to drop child widgets onto those separate pages.

Is this implemented directly in Gtk#? Where can I examine the code for this? How can I implement this for my own custom widgets? I want to create a notebook-like navigation control (similar to MS Outlook 2007/2010/2013) that can be designed using drag-and-drop with Stetic.

I have already tried searching through the source for [MonoDevelop and Gtk#](https://github.com/mono). It seems to me this may be implemented in a similar manner with additional classes and attributes like in Visual Studio with [Attributes and Design-Time Support](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a19191fh.aspx) but I cannot find any evidence of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Stetic designer in MonoDevelop simply does not support the concept of "pluggable" widget design or commands. It's just written the way it is for the controls it supports and anything else has to be added via the **Custom Widget** widget and manipulated via code.

Answer (score 0):

In MonoDevelop, Stetic is defined as a member in AddIns. Technically, it is always available/installed, so it is not something you deal with from the Add In Manager.

So you are looking for:

```
MonoDevelop.GtkCore.dll
libstetic.dll
libsteticui.dll
```

During a monodevelop build, assuming you have monodevelop code local, those get built and placed in:

```
monodevelop/main/build/AddIns/MonoDevelop.GtkCore
```

The source code that you are looking for is at:

```
monodevelop/main/src/addins/*
```

I would highly recommend in order to jump-start you:

- git clone the monodevelop source repo
- cd into the repo
- ./configure --help (to figure out what options you need to use)
- Once you can build monodevelop, you can use that build version or (Xamarin
  Starter+) to open workspace MonoDevelop.mdw (in root dir of repo)
- Navigate to:
- Main / Addins / MonoDevelop.GtkCore / libstetic
- Main / Addins / MonoDevelop.GtkCore / libsteticui

Have fun storming the castle ;-)

Comment: It looks like the actions are registered in [objects.xml](https://github.com/mono/monodevelop/blob/6e87c2c761c7bf22b2c079f9818c7f4967b3bb1f/main/src/addins/MonoDevelop.GtkCore/libstetic/wrapper/objects.xml#L965) and implemented in [Notebook.cs](https://github.com/mono/monodevelop/blob/master/main/src/addins/MonoDevelop.GtkCore/libstetic/wrapper/Notebook.cs#L166). So, this functionality is built directly into the libstetic plugin, where as VS implements it via Attributes and a "Designer" class. Am I out of luck on custom designer support without hard-coding my widget directly into libstetic?

Comment: Ok, I thought you were looking for a way to embedded a MD GUI designer look-alike into another app. In GTK# if you are inheriting from one of the widgets base case, you can just class tag it with  [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(true)] and it shows up in the Toolbox (someone else with just that assembly (no source), adds it as any other assembly to their project references and it is in the toolbox. As far as writing a custom widget, it is totally up to you.

Comment: You can create a hybrid/composite widget consisting of other std. widgets, inherit just one existing widget and customize it, or go all the way to the bottom and use something like Gtk drawing container. Painting, custom props, attributes, etc are up to you. That help?

Comment: To elaborate a bit more - I want to create an "Outlook style" navigation widget in Gtk#, similar to [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43181/A-Serious-Outlook-Style-Navigation-Pane-Control). I probably can do this by combining a VButtonBox for the "tabs" and two cells of a VBox. But I also want that control, if possible, to be "design-time" aware in Stetic so I can easily add/remove pages and drag-and-drop widgets without mucking about in the code. That "Serious Outlook control" for WinForms provides this via a series of classes assigned with the "[Designer]" attribute.

Comment: That would be a lot of work to repo that in old tech like GTK#2/Gtk2.x. Before writing that much code, I'd look at Gtk3 (non-std under mono, but working is ...slowly... on-going and you would have to give up on RAD GUIs, nothing beats VS RAD GUI Designers, unless you move to something like cross-platform QT (one of the best x-plat GUIs out there) and C++.